# Scalability of C server implementation based on pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, server, pthreads

I am wondering about the feasibility of the following basic implementation of a server and how well it would scale. I know that large-scale, distributed servers should probably be written in a language like Erlang, but I'm interested in the viability of the following code "these days".

Other than bugs/issues I'd primarily like to know 3 things:

1. C headers have many with compatibility methods/structs/etc. Some of which do similar things. Is this a correct "modern" way to handle incoming IPv4 and IPv6 connections?
2. How scalable is it? If I have a single VPN and don't need a distributed server, is it adequate for todays applications? (Potentially thousands/[millions](http://blog.whatsapp.com/196/1-million-is-so-2011) of concurrent connections? I appreciate the latter would also very much be hardware dependent!)

---

```
// SimpleCServer.c
// Adapted from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/print/bgnet_A4.pdf
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <pthread.h>

// The port users will be connecting to
#define PORT "12345"

// Prototype for processing function
void *processRequest(void *sdPtr);

// Get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa) {
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // Basic server variables
    int sockfd = -1;    // Listen on sock_fd
    int new_fd;         // New connection on new_fd
    int yes=1;
    int rv;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    // pthread variables
    pthread_t workerThread;         // Worker thread
    pthread_attr_t threadAttr;      // Set up detached thread attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    // Server hints
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // Loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {

        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(2);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // All done with this structure
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    // SOMAXCONN - Maximum queue length specifiable by listen. (128 on my machine)
    if (listen(sockfd, SOMAXCONN) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(4);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    // Main accept() loop
    while (1) {

        // Accept
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        // Get IP Address for log
        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        // Process the request on a new thread. Spawn (detaching) worker thread
        pthread_create(&workerThread, &threadAttr, processRequest, (void *)((intptr_t)new_fd));

    }

    return 0;
}

void *processRequest(void *sdPtr) {

    int sd = (int)sdPtr;

    fprintf(stderr, "Processing fd: %d\n", sd);

    // Processing goes here
    FILE *fpIn =    fdopen(sd, "r");
    FILE *fpOut =   fdopen(sd, "w");
    fprintf(fpOut, "Processing fd %d on server.", sd);
    fflush(fpOut);
    //

    fclose(fpIn);
    fclose(fpOut);
    close(sd);

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, each connection consumes a local port. Therefore, the number of *concurrent* connection is hard limited by unsigned short, that is 65536 (so millions are out of question).  There are also other limitations you may or may not care about.

Second, thread creation is somewhat expensive. Consider pre-allocating a thread pool.

Third, a code for reading data from the connection is missing. I assume that the intention is for each thread to issue a `recv` system call. This may lead to many thousands outstanding system calls, each consuming kernel resources. Using `poll` is way more scalable.

Finally, a code review. Your `main` does way too much. Variables are declared too far away from their uses. Consider restructuring. At least 2 functions (`setup_listener_socket` and `mainloop`) must be realized.

Comment: Thanks! I am not 100% sure what you mean in the first paragraph, however [this SF question](http://serverfault.com/questions/533611/how-do-high-traffic-sites-service-more-than-65535-tcp-connections) seems to indicate more than 65536 connections are possible. I did wonder about thread pools though, I shall go hunting for a decent implementation.

Comment: "*each connection consumes a local port.*" This is plain wrong! The server listens on exactly one port, that's it. The accepted socket does **not** occupy any port. What each connection does use is a socket descriptor, which indeed is a limited system resource.

Comment: Nope.  Same local port for all connections.

Comment: I stand corrected

Comment: +1 for thread pools. You definitely don't want 1 million threads fighting for the scheduler's attention.